# Prove that if $\rm Ax = 0_m$ for every $\mathrm x \in \mathbb R^n$, then $\rm A = O_{m \times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

> Let $A$ be an $ m \times n $ matrix. Suppose that $Ax = 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb R^n$. Show that $A$ is the zero matrix.

Looking to get some help with this proof.

Comment: thanks for the revision. Any ideas about this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(\forall \mathrm x \in \mathbb R^n) (\mathrm A \mathrm x = \mathrm 0_m) \implies \mathrm A = \mathrm O_{m \times n}$$

Taking the contrapositive,

$$\mathrm A \neq \mathrm O_{m \times n} \implies \neg (\forall \mathrm x \in \mathbb R^n) (\mathrm A \mathrm x = \mathrm 0_m)$$

Or, equivalently,

$$\mathrm A \neq \mathrm O_{m \times n} \implies (\exists \mathrm x \in \mathbb R^n) (\mathrm A \mathrm x \neq \mathrm 0_m)$$

Suppose that $a_{ij} \neq 0$. Thus, $\mathrm A \mathrm e_j \neq \mathrm 0_m$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ has a non-zero element, say, $A_{ij}$. Let $e_j$ be a vector whose $j$-th element is $1$ and other elements are $0$. Then
$$
Ae_j = A_{(j)} \neq 0
$$
where $A_{(j)}$ is the $j$-th column of $A$. A contradiction.